# How do I invoke a method from my helper module in my config/routes.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, config, ruby-on-rails-5, helper

I’m using Rails 5.  How do I get my confnig/routes.rb file to recognize a function I have defined in a helper module?  In my app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb file I have

```
  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
```

and then in my config/routes.rb file I have

```
 get '/', to: 'users#show',  constraints: lambda { |request| SessionsHelper.logged_in? }
```

However upon loading my application, I’m getting the error

```
undefined method `logged_in?' for SessionsHelper:Module
```

What is the right way to invoke the helper method from my module?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this, and you shouldn't do this. Your routes file has no concept of the session in which your current user's authorization is stored, that's provided by your controller *after* a route has been selected and the correct controller has been instantiated. Authorization doesn't belong in your routes file as a constraint anyways.

Your controllers should be responsible for rendering a 422 "unauthorized" if your `current_user` isn't set to an expected value. Do this in a `before_action` callback.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_login

  # ...

  protected

  def require_login
    redirect_to login_path unless current_user
  end
end
```

You would typically place the `require_login` functionality and `before_action` callback in your `ApplicationController`, and then selectively whitelist controllers that don't require authentication with `skip_before_action`. Many gems already exist that provide this exact setup, with a ton of extra functionality. See [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for example.

Comment: My goal is that if the user is logged in, when someone visits the root, they will be redirected to the users home page.  By reading your answer, I'm not clear on how I would achieve that.

Comment: @Natalia Exactly as I've written it, with a `before_action` and a `redirect_to` in the correct controller, whichever one is handling your `root` action

Comment: I don't have any controller set up for the root url, so woudl taht just default ot the application controller?  Even so, by putting this "before_action :require_login" taht woudl apply to every action in my that controller, right, but that's not what I want.  I only want to redirect from the root path ("/") if they are logged in.  In no other case do I want such a redirect.

Comment: Then put the redirect inside the method, or use `before_action :redirect, only: :index`, or just render the correct view from within the action via `render 'users/show'`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Devise? If yes then you should do it like this:

```
authenticated 
  get '/', to: 'users#show'
end
```

More details in Devise's code: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L294

Comment: Why does everyone keep asking me if I use devise?  No I don't.

Comment: Because Devise is most popular Rails gem for authentication. Anyway you can look at the devise's code and understand that they insert warden rack middleware to get info about authentication state. You should use @meagar advice.